# What is routing? Why is "routing" needed in single page web apps?

Tags: url-routing, react-router

I understood that routing libraries for SPAs like https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router help to parse the URL and put the app into a corresponding state of a state machine.

Is there more to routing than this?

Why is routing needed in the first place?

Why are URLs important? For example in a desktop app there are no URLs, so what's the big deal about them in a web app?

Comment: All URL are URI while desktop uses URI's.

Comment: Excellent question, I was about to ask the same. This may become increasingly relevant, for two reasons: (1) There is a trend for web apps to become ever more similar to (routing-free) desktop apps: PWAs. (2) It is very easy to manage the "route" in one's React state. One needs that state anyway, so one might as well add the extra info. What remains true is that routing protects against navigation _outside_ the app (F5, back button etc.), and it can help bookmarking special views of the app. But these features may not be worth the hassle of routing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I also have this problem: "Why do we need routing?". You can write apps without routing at all. The code can get messy but still, it is not impossible.

My biggest reason for having routing is because, if the user hits the Back button of the browser (Forward button as well, for that matter), they will not be navigating within the app. The user might expect to navigate within the app using the history of the different "pages" they loaded previously. Instead, they will be thrown out of the web app. Hitting the Refresh button would also throw them to the root of the app.

From the user's point of view, it is a regular web app (they doesn't need to know how it is designed: SPA or otherwise) and it should work as any web app/website should work. Routing ensures this, doesn't it?

Answer (score 22):

This is a very good question, and one that I don't see discussed as often as I think it should be. The short answer is that often, in a Single Page Web Application, you don't need routing. If you are building an application which doesn't require its pages to be indexed by Google, and you either don't care, or don't want the user to be able to Bookmark pages, then there is no reason to implement routing.
In an SPA, routing adds additional complexity and effort, so if you can avoid doing it, you should. Of course, modern frameworks such as Angular and React provide facilities for making routing much easier, but even then, some things can be hard to do with routing, for example animating between pages.
A good example of a web application where routing would be redundant would be a multi-page form which you want to control the user's passage through and possibly prevent them from returning to pages which have become inapplicable.
Implementing such a form with routes would be a nightmare as you would have to prevent the user from visiting certain pages in their history.

It's useful to ask yourself what a route actually is in an SPA. It's easy to think of it as just a 'web-page', but what it really is is a state, and when you navigate between routes, what you are really doing is navigating between different states of the app. The fact that the appearance of the app may change between states is incidental to what is really going on. So what a route does is give the user a means of returning to particular states of the app.
You should only implement a route in an SPA when there is a state of the app which you want the user to be able to return to.
An alternative, and perhaps more useful way of doing this, would be to implement Undo and Redo mechanisms.

Of course, even when you don't have routes, you still have to care about what happens when the user clicks the History Back button, but then you simply have a modal alert which warns them that they are about to leave the app should they proceed with the navigation.

Comment: This is a really well thought answer. I've experienced this problem myself. If your SPA should behave in a more flow manner, router adds more problems and solves none. Routing assumes you can visit any url hash indepedently, but often times in a flow the current view depends of the state and input of the previous ones.

Comment: May be too naive for me to ask, but could you please tell how the behaviour while clicking the 'Back' button controlled better through routing ? What happens when a Back button is clicked after routing ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you rephrase it please?

Answer (score 10):

In desktop applications you have buttons and other controls to get what you want. So routing in UI apps would be the set of all UI controls.
In web apps on the other hand, all functionality is accessed via some text which is the links and the parameters.

A URL is the path to access a functionality. Routing is like the mechanism to decide which functionality to call based on the provided URL and params.

So basically routing is a mapping between an URL and the functionality of a web server.

Answer (score 5):

Routing in SPAs is used to load certain parts of the web app e.g. `yourappurl.com/profile/userid/` will load the profile part of an SPA with the right user profile corresponding to the userid. This can be seen in the [GitHub example you provided](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router):

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="users" component={Users}>
    <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
</Route>
```

SPA refers to the fact that in general you have an index.html as your "main view" and then depending on the routing you add/remove certain parts from the index.html with frameworks like React or AngularJS etc.

Comment: Right, but what is the purpose of this ? Why is this good ? None of the deskop apps have such a feature. Why is this needed ?

Comment: @jhegedus It's really the only way to make a routing of any kind, which seems intuitive enough given the nature of the web - it's all based on URLs. I guess someone at some point decided that routing should be done with URLs on SPAs as well. It seemed counterintuitive to me as well (for quite some time) but if you think about it, how else would you hide/show parts of the page? Sure you could write relative paths only but paths = URLs. Do you get where I am going with this? You have to have a path and paths mean URLs on the web. You can't segue between view controllers like on iOS etc.

Comment: "how else would you hide/show parts of the page" - just manipulate the dom from JS, the dom is independent of the URL

Comment: @jhegedus Correct, but that's what the framework does in the background anyway :) It is just supposed to make things easier by letting you route like on a desktop app. It helps with code reuse etc. because you don't have to show hide elements manually etc. When you route away from a partial view to another one it does a lot of UI things for you in the background so you can focus on the UI of the app and not the shuffling around of stuff that one does when writing vanilla JS code

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question from time to time.

I would like to say router in SPA is a component hierarchy helper.

As @tech4242 pointed out, we don't have an something like segue in iOS. So what should we use to help users navigate if we don't use router? We are talking about SPA here. So we can manage this in store or state. Yes, that's feasible but not preferable.

Try to think this from the perspective of using a component-oriented library (either React or Vue). Using router help us use a certain component for a specific route. When users move back and forth between different route, we are relying on the route to tell what component to display. We simply couple a component with a specific route, which makes our root component (normally called App) clear, maintainable and readable. Without router, either the root component or state would be messy and hard to maintain.