# How does a SPA router differentiate frontend from backend routes?

Tags: nginx, react-router, single-page-application

I understand [what SPA routing is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636411/what-is-routing-why-is-routing-needed-in-single-page-web-apps), but there is one aspect I never fully understood, and I don't know if the answer to the question is library specific, server-site specific, or both.

When running a SPA development server locally, the routing is obvious. For instance the frontend route `/user/login` is served by the development server under `https://<SERVER-IP>/user/login`.

However, how does that work in production? For example, in production there is an NGINX instance running that statically serves the SPA build files from `http://some-domain/some/path`, in particular the main `http://some-domain/some/path/index.html`. On server site, this typically requires a certain configuration that ensures that requests on sub-paths get redirected to the `index.html`, as explained e.g. by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502404/1804173) in case of NGINX.

What isn't clear to me: How can the app extract the frontend route from the URL after redirection? For instance: If the request is `http://some-domain/some/path/user/login` how does the app router knows the relevant part of the URL is `/user/login`? I see two possible explanation:

- Either it is possible to maintain the "base URL" information in the redirect, or
- Does this in general require a special (production specific) configuration of the frontend router library?

Comment: The router needs to know what its root is to do the relative paths below that. For React Router, for example: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks that should answer it! I was actually coming from Reach Router where I still have trouble finding this information in the docs, hence the confusion on my part...

Comment: It's called the same thing in Reach by the looks of it: https://reach.tech/router/api/Router

Comment: @jonrsharpe Perhaps. The _used internally_ and _sub directory of a larger app_ made it sound like it is something different to me (I thought "larger app" refers to another React App, unusual way to refer to the server hosting). The wording on the React Router makes it much more clear that it is an essential configuration.